# 'Bad request' error while sending a request with special characters in Robot Framework to Postman API

Tags: windows-10, postman, robotframework, special-characters, testautomationfx

I'm doing an automation using Robot Framework (in Visual Studio) that makes a request to Postman API, but it won't work if I send a request that contains words with special characters like "Pré-Pago".
If I try to make the request manually, in Postman, it works fine. But through the automation, it returns an error (bad request). It will only work if I remove the special character "´".

- I'm Using UTF-8 in VS Code.
- The requests works properly to all my co-workers, but it stopped working for me after I formatted my computer and reinstalled everything, including the robot libraries.
  Current using: Robot Framework 5.0.1 (Python 3.9.5 on win32). Windows 10.
  I'm using the correct language package in Windows.

My co-workers are using the same VS Code settings, and same versions of Python and Robot Framework. I started facing this issue after I formatted my computer, before that, the automation that makes a request to Postman API was working fine with or without special characters.

Comment: I don't have a fix but the post keyword shows the request in RF logs. This is one of those cases where you have to compare successful and failing messages.